# Регулярное выражение для подсчета групп

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Необходимость подсчитать вхождения в группах из такого текста:

> ID=2032 The man worked hard but she wouldn't give him the
>   opportunity.\nEventually, filled with disappointment and emptiness his
>   heart broke.\nThe woman who accompanied him all this time silently
>   watched him change.\n\nThis is the story of a man disappointed with
>   the world and a woman who was there supporting him.

Считать нужно символы `\n` они представлены именно в виде текста, не сами переносы строк. Я попробовал составить такое выражение, но оно почему-то не матчит группы:

```
^ID=([0-9]{0,})(\n)+(\\n)+(\n)+
```

Как его подправить, что бы в группы были записаны вхождения `\n` *их может быть до 2х штук подряд, в один матч запихнуть*.

текст для теста:

```
ID=2035
世の中には様々な職種がある。 \nある者は頭を使う仕事をし、またある者は体を使う仕事をする。\n\n彼は頭よりも体を動かすタイプで、何よりポジティブだった。\nそれは、彼がこれから幾度と無くぶつかる困難を乗り越える力になるだろう。\n\nこれは、前向きな男の人生の話。

ID=2034
人生は平等ではない。明日を約束されている者と、明日が見えない者がいる。 \n少女は後者だった。生を授かった瞬間から、病院の外では生きらない運命…。\n\nそんな少女を、数年間看てきた一人の看護師…。\n二人は家族以上の絆で結ばれていたが、いつか訪れる別れを覚悟していた。\n\nこれは、明日に怯える少女と、日々別れを覚悟する看護師の話。

ID=2041
事故で両親を亡くした彼女に残された家族は、年の離れた弟一人だけだった。\n彼女は一生懸命働き、幼い弟は一人で留守番をしていた。\n\n彼女はそれを申し訳なく思って、時間がある時は弟を連れて故郷の海辺を歩いた。\n明日になれば、また弟を置いて仕事の日々…時間の許す限り弟と一緒にいたい。\n\n弟と過ごすその一瞬一瞬は、二度と戻って来ないのだから。\n\nこれは、弟と一緒にいることの出来ない姉の申し訳ない気持ちを綴った話。
```

Еще один из вариантов, но добавить бы туда не обязательные группы, что бы хватал все, даже те где идут по 2 `\n\n`, чего данный вариант не делает

`^ID=\d+\n+.+(\\n).+(\\n){1,}.+(\\n).+$`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что вы ходите вытащить? Значения `ID` и текст под ними? У меня так получилось `ID=(\d+)[\n\r](.+)` -> https://regex101.com/r/5UT8C4/1

Comment: `Считать нужно символы \n` Нужно подсчитать эти символы, разделяя на группы от `ID` до ｀ID｀

Comment: регулярные выражения сами по себе не предназначены для подсчета. Надо одной регуляркой захватить требуемые участки (от ID до ID например). А потом отдельно посчитать вхождения `\n`с помощью строковых функций или тех же регулярок с единственной группой захвата, но выполнять саму регурлярку в цикле или получая массив результатов (смотря какой подход существует/удобнее в вашем языке)

Comment: @Mike: Я понимаю, но мне необходимо сделать такой матч, что бы после этого представить хинт для перевода текста, при этом необходимо соблюдать кол-во переносов строк. Если это возможно вообще.

Comment: У меня еще есть такой вариант, но он хватает случайно 1 вхождение из группы `^ID=\d+\n+.+(\\n){1,}.+\n`

Comment: Но как в вашем языке представлена работа с регулярками, что именно он готов возвращать ? Вы можете конечно указать некоторое количество не обязательных групп захвата и потом в языке собственно проверить сколько из них сработало. Или если бы у вас был perl, вы бы могли в саму регулярку встроить исполнимый код, который бы действительно посчитал и выдал количество в переменной

Comment: `var count = "My String \\n another string ".Split(new[] { "\\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();` ?

Comment: Для такой задачи регулярки не нужны. Достаточно того что есть в C# - методы работы со строками и LINQ.

Comment: @Bulson Как вы тогда предложите учесть вариант с 2мя переносами? _я не про сплит, а учет того что там именно 2 переноса_

Comment: @LLENN Давайте определимся с тем, как должен выглядеть результат. Например, у вас есть `string s = @"Abc.\nD e,f.\n___.\n\nNew line."`. Что вы хотите получить?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew добавил картинку для ясности того что нужно получить.

Comment: Объясните, зачем вам именно группы. `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?:(?:\\r)?\\n)+")` находит всё, что нужно. Многое зависит и от того, что вы делаете: ищете совпадения или производите замену в тексте. [См. демо](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5c%5cr%29%3f%5c%5cn%29%2b&i=Abc.%5cnD+e%2cf.%5cn___.%5cn%5cnNew+line.)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, такой вариант мне подойдет, только придется все же на группы разбивать доп. регуляркой. Не замена текста, ни совпадения, а нужно сделать плейсхолдер для переводчика, что бы он не делал много переносов строк, т.к. это сказывается на ресурсах одной из программ, и она отказывается их грузить.

Comment: Я работаю как раз в подобной фирме :), проблема мне понятна. Т.е. всё-таки вы заменяете. Ещё раз, что должно быть на выходе? Заключить их в теги? `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?:(?:\\r)?\\n)+", "<internal>$&</internal>")`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91516/discussion-between-llenn-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего сделать всё в 2 этапа:

- Вчитать файл по 3 строчки (так как у вас фиксированная структура сегментов),
- Получить количество переносов с помощью `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?:(?:\\r)?\\n)+").Count`.

Если у вас в тексте нет `\r`, можно обойтись  и более простым `@"(?:\\n)+"`.